# Does a polynomial in $\Bbb R[x]$ of degree $n$ always have at least one real root?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, roots

> Establish a bijective correspondence between the maximal ideals of $\Bbb R[x]$ and points in the upper half plane.

The maximal ideals of $\Bbb R[x]$ are the principal ideals $\langle p\rangle$ where $p$ is a monic irreducible polynomial. I found out that $p$ must be of degree $1$ or $2$ with the condition that the discriminant is negative. I know that these two cases give me irreducible polynomials over $\Bbb R$, but why cannot $p$ be of degree $>2$?

If $p$ is of degree say $3$, then $p$ would have $3$ roots, but if all of the roots are complex, then $p$ would still be irreducible over $\Bbb R$? Why is this case not possible? I tried to find a result which would state that a degree $n$ polynomial over $\Bbb R$ would have always at least one real root, but I couldn't find any.

Comment: $x^n+1$ often doesn't have a real root, so real roots are not the solution to your issue.

Comment: A real polynomial of even degree need not have a real root, the simplest example is $x^2+1$.

Comment: The existence of at least one real root of a polynomial with real coefficients is only guaranteed if the degree is odd. In this case the intermediate theorem and the limits for $x\to \pm \infty$ immediately gives the existence of a real root.

Comment: I see. What might be the problem here then? I.e why cannot a polynomial of degree greater than $2$ be irreducible so that it could be a maximal ideal?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_root_theorem

Comment: This needs the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra for a complete answer. By it we know $f(X)$ has  roots in the complex numbers. If any is real then $f$ is not irreducible. If $a+ib$ is a root so is $a-ib$ (check that ) so $f$ has a factor $X^2-2aX+(a^2+b^2)$ so is not irreducible.

Comment: The title only asks about whether a polynomial in $\mathbb R[x]$ always has at least one real root, but in the body there is a much more complicated question. It is not obvious that it is equivalent to the question in the title. The mentioned hint seems to adress only the proof than an odd degree polynomial always has at least one real root, or do I miss something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see that an irreducible polynomial $p\in\mathbb{R}[X]$ can only have degree $1$ or $2$ proceed as follows.

The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra says that $p$ has at least one root in $\mathbb{C}[X]$, say $a+ib$, so $p(a+ib)=0$. Taking complex conjugates we have that $\overline{p(a+ib)}=0$.

For all complex numbers we have that $\overline{z_1 z_2}=\overline{z_1}\overline{ z_2}$ and $\overline{z_1 + z_2}=\overline{z_1}+\overline{ z_2}$; and for real $z$ we have $\overline{z}=z$. Hence we have that $p(\overline{a+ib})=\overline{p(a+ib)}=0$.

So consider the two cases $b=0$ and $b\ne 0$.

In the first case we use the Remainder Theorem in $\mathbb{R}[X]$ to get that $p(X)=(X-a)q(X)$ with $q\in\mathbb{R}[X]$. As $p$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{R}[X]$ we have that $p(X)=c(X-a)$ is of degree $1$.

In the second case we use the Remainder Theorem in $\mathbb{C}[X]$ twice to get that $p(X)=(X^2-2aX+a^2+b^2)q(x)$ with $q\in\mathbb{C}[X]$. However since $p(X)=\overline{p(X)}$ and $\overline{(X^2-2aX+a^2+b^2)}=(X^2-2aX+a^2+b^2)$ we must have that $\overline{q(X)}=q(X)$, and so actually $q\in\mathbb{R}[X]$. However $p$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{R}[X]$ so we must have that $p(X)=c(X^2-2aX+a^2+b^2)$ is of degree $2$.